# Compare different writeln "implementations"

Tags: python, file

What is "more pythonic" / more effective / nicer:

```
fp.write(some_long_string)
fp.write('\n')
```

or

```
fp.write(some_long_string + '\n')
```

or

```
fp.writelines([some_long_string])
```

Comment: `writelines` does not add newlines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Python language does not have a writeln() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575619/why-python-language-does-not-have-a-writeln-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get away without a function call:

```
print >>fp, some_long_string
```