# Pyserial: emulate a RS232 barcode scanner

Tags: python, serial-port, barcode, pyserial

I have a cash register that can be equipped with a serial bar code scanner (EAN13) and I would like to send the code from Odoo (OpenERP) directly using a real RS232 (DB9) port. I've connected the cable but I have no idea hot to send the code to the machine. I mean I know how basically Pyserial works but I don't know if the configuration is right because the ELGIN (the producer) doesn't share any kind of technical information. All I know is that the equipment is compatible with any EAN13 serial BC scanner.
The setting I'm using are the following:

`--- Settings: /dev/ttyS0  9600,8,N,1
--- RTS: active    DTR: active    BREAK: inactive
--- CTS: inactive  DSR: inactive  RI: active    CD: inactive
--- software flow control: inactive
--- hardware flow control: inactive
--- data escaping: raw  linefeed: CR/LF`

And this is how I'm trying to send the code to the cash register:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)  
print ser.name          
ser.write("1001000000006")     
ser.close()
```

Since seems a "one-way-communication" I did't figure out where the error is because Pyhton send the code and exit without errors. Any tips?

Comment: You need to attach a real barcode scanner to a test program so you can verify the port parameters and capture the exact sequences that are sent by it. That will give you a starting point to figure out how your implementation differs from the scanner.

Comment: I fear you're right. But I'm trying to avoid it because it will be an unnecessary piece of hardware after... I'll see if I can find it one for some days to test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most RS232 barcode scanners are sending EANs in raw form, but in line by line form. Every line has to end with `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working with a `ser.write("1001000000006\r\n")`. Problem is I don't have any output from the cash register.

Comment: try `writeln`, but not sure if its implemented there

Comment: No. In Python there is just write(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575619/why-python-language-does-not-have-a-writeln-method